# numpy vectorization instead of loop

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have the following equation:

[image]

where v, mu are |R^3, where Sigma is |R^(3x3) and where the result is a scalar value. Implementing this in numpy is no problem:

```
result = np.transpose(v - mu) @ Sigma_inv @ (v - mu)
```

Now I have a bunch of v-vectors (lets call them V \in |R^3xn) and I would
like to execute the above equation in a vectorized manner so that, as 
a result I get a new vector Result \in |R^1xn.

```
# pseudocode
Result = np.zeros((n, 1))
for i,v in V:
    Result[i,:] = np.transpose(v - mu) @ Sigma_inv @ (v - mu)
```

I looked at **np.vectorize** but the documentation suggests that its just the same as looping over all entries which I would prefer not to do. What would be an elegant vectorized solution?

As a side node: n might be quite large and a |R^nxn matrix will certainly not fit into my memory!

edit: working code sample

```
import numpy as np

S = np.array([[1, 2], [3,4]])
V = np.array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

Res = np.zeros((V.shape[1], 1))
for i in range(V.shape[1]):
    v = np.transpose(np.atleast_2d(V[:,i]))
    Res[i,:] = (np.transpose(v) @ S @ v)[0][0]

print(Res)
```

Comment: It would be easier if you would provide a minimal working example of what you would like to achieve, even if using loops (e.g. including `import` statements and definitions of all symbols you use).

Comment: True: I added a minimal example

Comment: I would look into `np.einsum`, although I believe it is one of the most cryptic function in `numpy`, it may be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of [`matrix-multiplication`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) and [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->j',V,S.dot(V))
```

Comment: You probably need a reshape at the end to match the MWE, but other than that, this is excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
res = np.diag(V.T @ S @ V).reshape(-1, 1)
```

It seems to provide the same result as you want.

```
import numpy as np

S = np.array([[1, 2], [3,4]])
V = np.array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

Res = np.zeros((V.shape[1], 1))
for i in range(V.shape[1]):
    v = np.transpose(np.atleast_2d(V[:,i]))
    Res[i,:] = (np.transpose(v) @ S @ v)[0][0]

res = np.diag(V.T @ S @ V).reshape(-1, 1)

print(np.all(np.isclose(Res, res)))
# output: True
```

Although there is probably a more memory efficient solution using `np.einsum`.

Comment: thanks for the hints! The problem with your solution is that "n" in my application is quite large so a matrix R^{n x n} will definitely not fit into memory.

Comment: The solution by @Divarak is superior to this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution:

```
import numpy as np

S = np.array([[1, 2], [3,4]])
V = np.array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

Res = np.sum((V.T @ S) * V.T, axis=1)
```

Comment: My problem was that V.T @ S @ V will be too large to fit into memory as it will be |R^{n x n}

Comment: @juqa Yes, I've changed the answer to use only n x 2 arrays. It's essentially the same as Divakar's answer, although einsum might be faster than multiplication and sum.

Comment: thanks, I benchmarked both solutions for a vector with 5.000.000 entries and your hunch was correct: einsum took ~100ms while your solution took ~150ms  (benchmarked over multiple iterations).

Answer (score 0):

This are multiplications of matrix/vector stacks. [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) can do that after bringing S and V into the correct shape:

```
S = S[np.newaxis, :, :]
VT = V.T[:, np.newaxis, :]
V = VT.transpose(0, 2, 1)    

tmp = np.matmul(S, V)
Res = np.matmul(VT, tmp)

print(Res)
#[[[2700]]
# [[3040]]
# [[3400]]
# [[3780]]
# [[4180]]
# [[4600]]]
```